# Determining which CGPath was tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics

I am looking for what I would call the inverse of CGPathContainsPoint. I have a series of clickable regions in a UIView and if a user taps, I need to find out which region the user tapped.

Other than using CGPathContainsPoint to check each region, is there a better way to simply determine which CGPath was tapped?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (CGPathContainsPoint(path, NULL, touchpositionInView, NO)){
BOOL PathContainsPoint = YES;
}

if (CGPathContainsPoint(path2, NULL, touchpositionInView, NO)){
BOOL Path2ContainsPoint = YES;
}
//...
```

I dont see what is the problem with this code?

Comment: What I was really looking for was a more efficient way of checking, that is, to be able to identify which CGPath was clicked without having to check each one individually.

Comment: ahh, i think i know what you mean. you could combine your paths by doing pathByAddingPath. and then if(!pathcontainspoint(combinedPath,NULL, touchpositioninview,NO){  nslog(@"something here");         }